# Get IE8 conditional style sheet for responsive web design to work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I've created a mobile first responsive web page. It is working lovely in all the major browsers to my liking and is looking good on mobile phones and tablets too.

Last part is I want it to look decent in IE8.

I've read here on #3 (http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/mobile/responsibly-responsive-mobile-first-responsive-design-part-2/) you can simply serve a specific style sheet for IE9 and lower with the desktop version styles using conditional comments.

I created ie.css with my desktop styles and have added this conditional commenting to the head section however no luck, I still get the mobile styles in IE8 and lower.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">

<!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" media="all">
<![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

Any ideas on whats going wrong? I've double checked that my ie.css file is sitting there in the directory right next to my index.html just like style.css. Is there some other reason this would not work?
Thanks,

Comment: Did you inspect your page to see if your css file is being loaded correctly?

Comment: @BrianGlaz How do I see in IE inspector if the css file is being loaded correctly? When I inspect and look in the head section I do not see the conditional comment to load the ie.css file. I assume it should be there but do not see it.

Comment: Ok well I've learned how to use the F12 Inspector Network tab to see the resources the page is loading (http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-faster-with-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-9/) It does not seem to be loading the ie.css file. But why? It's in the same location as style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i read that correctly, you just want to target ie8?
first off, place html5shiv above all of your style sheets...unless you have style sheets that literally have no styles for ie. html5shiv needs be rendered first so it can tell ie those are elements and it needs to style them accordingly.
i'm still confused about what you want exactly, and not sure if you are targeting less than ie8, so lets just fix ie8 issue(s):

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">

<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->

EDIT
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" media="all">
<![endif]-->  
<![if !IEMobile]>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" media="all">
<![endif]>
```

all we've done is move html5shim above all of the style sheets. then comes the style sheet for every other browser. then comes a style sheet only for ie8. then comes the style sheet for less than ie 8 and not ie mobile.
take note: i changed the version from less than 9 to less than 8, so there's no chance of cross-referencing each other, cancelling/adding styles to each other.
again, i'm not clear thats what you wanted, but this fixes the issues i see. lmk if i misunderstood something.
EDIT: looks like the mobile not (`if !IEMobile`) needs different syntax, so i'm assuming trying them separate will fix it. here's reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/12/08/targeting-mobile-optimized-css-at-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested here (http://bit.ly/MvB2G4) but I still get the mobile styles in IE8.

Comment: huh. i'm looking @ mobile cc right now. see what i can dig up

Comment: i think you want a different syntax. i edited the answer

Comment: Hooray it's pulling in ie.css now! It looks a bit messed up but I can adjust the styles now that I can see them. It doesn't seem to be pulling in ie8.css but maybe I don't need that? Thanks! The respond.js was a faster fix but I'm glad to know I can do it another way as well without it.

Comment: idk why ie8 isn't working. could be minor syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Respond.JS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) - a javascript polyfill to make css media queries work in IE8

Comment: I've used it for another project but is it necessary? This is a very simple page it just displays content. Most people viewing it will get there via mobile devices so I hate to have to load a js library just for IE8

Comment: Nothing is necessary, so not really. You seemed to be willing to load extra files for IE already. I like using it because it allows my existing media queries to work for IE too, without using additional css files. Either way it's an extra static resource.

Comment: I guess if it only loads it for IE8 and lower it is essentially the same idea of loading an extra file. I'll give it a go. Still not sure though why it's not loading my ie.css file.

Comment: I've tried adding respond.JS (http://bit.ly/MvB2G4) but it doesn't seem to be loading those resources either for some reason. Is something wrong with my conditional comment?

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted to do it but this method seems to be working for me (http://www.javascriptoo.com/respond-js) My page (http://bit.ly/1aAxvS2)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you, add some jQuery to remove your responsive stylesheet when web page load in a ie8 below versions, So add new style sheet for ie 8 and below versions

```
if (jQuery.browser.version >= 8.0) {
    $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="style.css"]').remove();
}
```

or if you need responsive for 1.e8 0r 7, make sure that you are added these meta tags and scripts below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have styles within your mobile stylesheet that aren't decalred within yout IE sheet. therefore they aren't getting overwritten. You could exclude the mobile stylesheet on non IE stylesheets.

```
<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" media="all"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I've added that line '<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all"> <!--<![endif]-->' as shown above and still does not work.